# Umbraco 7.4.1 Performance Issues

Tags: azure, content-management-system, umbraco

I've got a site that was in 7.2.8 that I migrated to 7.4.1. There are quite a few host names I have to support given our development, test, staging and production environments.

I was hosting the site on Windows Azure but it was too slow for our client's liking. We moved it to their data center. Their production site runs great now, but we're looking at deploying updates and their staging site runs DOG slow. The code is nearly identical asside from some web.config updates (SSL cookies, X-Frame-Options host header, and a few other minor things).

What could be causing this problem? I've noticed that Umbraco seems to need some time to "do it's thing" before speeding up but I can't make heads or tails of it. Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: This question is off-topic, as it's not a specific programming question; it's an open-ended discussion on performance tuning. Plus, it's not clear about the staging site (e.g. is it local too? on Azure?). Regardless... not a question for StackOverflow.

Comment: Try asking over on our.umbraco.org instead.

Answer (score 0):

What is the staging site hosted on? Can you provide more details? It's possible the staging server is underpowered. If you have uSync turned on, and have a lot of DocTypes, that can slow up the site startup. Other things to look out for are any custom startup events, and where the DB is hosted. If it's an Azure DB, it'll be super slow, unless you're forking out for one of the higher tiers.